# $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \arctan(nx)$ and set-valued limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Consider the sequence $a_n(x)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\arctan(nx)$.

[image: illustration of the sequence]

$(a_n)$ converges pointwise to $1$ if $x>0$, $-1$ if $x<0$ and $0$ if $x=0$. It does not converge uniformly as the limit function is not even continuous.

Would there be a definition of convergence (maybe in the framework of measures or distributions) with which $(a_n)$ would converge to a set-valued "function" (which would probably be $\{-1\}$ if $x<0$, $[-1,1]$ if $x=0$ and $\{1\}$ if $x>0$)?

Comment: Why is it not good enough for you that the limiting function is 0 at 0?

Comment: @zoli: Because I always try to go further ;)

Comment: Please, go further : D

Comment: @zoli No, seriously, I am just wondering if there is no other type of convergence for which $\arctan(nx)$ would converge to a set-valued object. I don't think there is, but I heard some people stating so... and I have doubts.

Comment: OK. Seriously: A function is a subset of pairs; that is a f is special relation.  Your dreamed up limit is a relation as well. So you are talking about a kind of convergence of relations, subsets if the ordered pairs at stake. Define measure on the rekations; on the priduct space of the domain and the (forgot the name of the other thing)...

Comment: Sorry for the typos. I am on my smarty.